# Apache/Mod Rewrite: Route everything to index.php?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm writing a front-controller that will handle page requests, by parsing

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].
```

I would like to get all requests routed to /index.php

Some examples as follows:

```
example.com/page2?foo=bar
example.com/page2/?foo=bar
example.com/page/action/123/
example.com/page/action/123
```

What is the regexp rule that i have to write in .htaccess ?

And do I need an extra rule so that example.com/images/ directory would work as 'normal' directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dir_under_rootdocument/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|png|js|css)$
RewriteRule (.*) dir_under_rootdocument/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Renard, can you clarify your answer?  It looks like it's saying "Anything that's not already index.php (to prevent loops) and not a web page should get redirected to index.php, passing the original query parameters to it"?